# Linear maps from finite-dimensional spaces are continuous. Proof?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I am trying to find a non-circular path that leads me to the following result:

> **Theorem 1.** Linear maps from a finite-dimensional normed linear space (to possibly infinite dimensional spaces) are continuous (or equivalently, bounded).

I know that this would follow from:

> **Result 2:** Any two norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.

But the proofs of the above fact that I have come across use the fact:

> **Result 3:** Closed and bounded subset of a finite-dimensional normed linear space are compact.

I know that this is Heine-Borel for $\mathbb R^n$ over $\mathbb R$ under the $l_p$ norms (which I know are equivalent).

But I don't have any reference for a proof for the general case which doesn't use any of the previous statements. I'd appreciate if someone can point me where to look.

(I have had a first course on topology, but no brush with functional analysis yet.)

---

**Note:** I want to show when the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The proof of result 2 only needs compactness of the unit ball in $\ell_1^n$ ($n$-space over $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ with the $1$-norm). See Linear Analysis by Bollobás page 60.

Comment: @JosephHarrison Many thanks for showing me the resource!

Comment: That's no problem, it is a good book with some difficult exercises. Best of luck!